# RS 2016 Unable to use Expression to filter in bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2016

I am using Reporting Services 2016. I have 6 charts that I need to only show the top 10 results. Currently, if the report only returns a value for 9 of the category groups, the report shows all of the category groups (values on x-axis), instead of the top 10. (see image below)
I understand why this is happening but am looking for a work around, or if this is going to be correct in a future release.

[image]

Also, if I try to use an expression to create a calculated field to flag which results to show if there are less than 10 that have a value. I get an error returned saying that aggregates cannot be used in filters.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have so many bars in not because SSRS doesn't filter them out, it's because they are all tied for the 10th spot with zero value and SSRS TOP 10 will always show all ties for 10th place.

You need to implement a tiebreaker condition in your expression based on another value or additionally add another filter which removes zero values from your chart.